# SQL Average of Rows and column at the same time - like matrix average

Tags: sql, sql-server, excel, t-sql

I have a table like this -
[image]

I want to group by Dept to get the total and average of four columns with multiple rows. The output should look like -
[image]
Can someone please help!

Answer (score 5):

Another option is with a CROSS APPLY

```
Select A.Dept     
      ,MonthTotal = sum(B.value)
      ,MonthAvg   = avg(B.value)
 From YourTable A
 Cross Apply ( values (month1)
                     ,(month2)
                     ,(month3)
                     ,(month4)
             ) B(value)
 Group By A.Dept
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you John.

Comment: @Paul Happy to help

Answer (score 1):

If you need to build it in Excel, then use the following two formulas:

[AVERAGEIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/AVERAGEIF-function-faec8e2e-0dec-4308-af69-f5576d8ac642)

[SUMIF](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/SUMIF-function-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b)

These formulas will take care of the empty values automatically.

Answer (score 0):

Using `GROUP BY`

```
  SELECT SUM(month1 + month2 + month3 + month4) AS MonthTotal,
         SUM(month1 + month2 + month3 + month4)/(COUNT(*) * 4) AS MonthAvg,
         dept
  FROM your_table
  GROUP BY dept
```

Answer (score 0):

First, you need to unpivot your data and after perform the aggregations

```
declare @table table (Dept varchar(30), Month1 decimal(16,4), Month2 decimal(16,4), Month3 decimal(16,4), Month4 decimal(16,4))
Insert @table (Dept, Month1, Month2, Month3,Month4) values
 ('Medicine'        , 80.06     ,80.0709    ,80.0709    ,80.8153)
,('Medicine'        , 61.64     ,null       ,81.8364    ,79.1241)
,('Medicine'        , 48.34     ,79.0159    ,null       ,null)
,('Medicine'        , null      ,87.5137    ,83.7288    ,75.454)
,('Non-Medicine'    , 85.13     ,89.36      ,89.36      ,89.36)
,('Non-Medicine'    , 82.21     ,91.2732    ,91.334     ,null)
,('Non-Medicine'    , 106.19    ,NULL       ,80.3801    ,82.2787)
,('Non-Medicine'    , 94.44     ,75.0055    ,75.4232    ,75.4335)
,('Non-Medicine'    , 119.77    ,87.6069    ,88.0649    ,null)

Select 
Dept
,Sum(Sales) 
,Avg(Sales)
FROM (
SELECT 
     Dept 
    ,Month 
    ,Sales
FROM
(
 SELECT 
     Dept
    ,Month1
    ,Month2
    ,Month3
    ,Month4
 FROM @table
) p  UNPIVOT (Sales For Month in (Month1,Month2,Month3,Month4) ) U
WHERE Sales Is not null
) x 

Group by 
Dept
```

Result

```
Dept                           Sum                                     Agv
------------------------------ --------------------------------------- ---------------------------------------
Medicine                       917.6700                                76.472500
Non-Medicine                   1502.6200                               88.389411
```